# Adding a list of URLs from an Excel file cell to a list in Python

Tags: python, excel

I have an Excel file with a column 'id' with product IDs and column 'imagelinks', where cells contain URL links to images for those products. Cells with links can contain several links, separated with commas.

I am trying to add the list of URLs from the Excel file to a list in Python, from which I can then download the images to my computer. However, I can't seem to return the list.
I have added an image of the excel file (see link).
Here is my code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import os

productID ='65212380'

[df = pd.read_excel("OLD_AP_Web_imageLinks_CatID.xlsx")
imagelinks = []
df_productID = df[df["id"] == productID]

for row in df_productID.iterrows():
    imagelinks.append(df_productID['imagelinks'])

dest_dir = f'//Users/ljimac/Documents/Website/{productID}'

try:
  os.mkdir(dest_dir)

except FileExistsError as e:
  print('The file path already exists!')

os.chdir(dest_dir)

for image in imagelinks:
file_name = image.split('/')[-2]
with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
    im = requests.get(image)
    f.write(im.content)
```

Comment: can you tell in the last line, what to want to do in "print(imagelinks)][1]". Also how you are handling the path here  like assigning dest_dir...

Comment: I have corrected the code, deleting the print line and adding the final part for downloading the images to a folder. The download part of the code is working, the only thing that seems to be giving me issues is getting the urls to the imagelinks list.

Answer (score 0):

I actually resolved getting the list by using `str.split()`.
Here is the code that is working for me for the first sheet:

```
df = pd.read_excel("OLD_AP_Web_imageLinks_CatID.xlsx")
imagelinks = []
# use str split on the column
df['imagelinks'] = df['imagelinks'].str.split(',') 

df_productID = df[df["id"] == productID]

for row in df_productID.iterrows():
    imagelinks.append(df.loc[0,'imagelinks'])
print(imagelinks)
```

However, it does not work for multiple sheets in an Excel file, only the first one. As soon as I add `(sheet_name=None)` to the `read.excel` method, the `str.split()` stops working. I tried a workaround by saving the `DataFrame` to a new Excel file, but the search parameters still only work  for the first sheet in the workbook.

Here is my latest code:

```
df = pd.read_excel("OLD_AP_Web_imageLinks_CatID.xlsx", sheet_name=None)

with pd.ExcelWriter('image_links.xlsx') as writer:  # <- HERE
    for name, df in df.items():
        df['imagelinks'] = df['imagelinks'].str.split(',')
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=name, index=False)
        
imagelinks = []

df_new = pd.read_excel('image_links.xlsx', sheet_name=None)
df_productID = df[df_new['id'] == productID]

for row in df_productID.iterrows():
    imagelinks =(df.loc[0,'imagelinks'])
print(imagelinks)
```

I can get the image links for the first sheet. If the product code is in any other sheet, I get this error:

```
File "/Users/ljimac/Documents/Coding_Projects/PWdemo/soup.py", line 63, in <module>
    df_productID = df[df_new['id'] == productID]
KeyError: 'id'
```

What am I missing?